# how can i get first img from html code by php

Tags: php

i want get first img from html code by php

i have this code

```
$text = '
<b>hello</b>
this is the first img
<img src="http://localhost/1.png" title="first img" />
other img
<img src="http://localhost/2.png" title="other" />
';
```

I want the first source image in a new variable

```
http://localhost/1.png
```

thanks

Comment: regex it... http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `preg_match` function

```
preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $text, $img);
echo $img[1]; // http://localhost/1.png
```

Comment: yours is actually smarter than mine because it alse looks for `img ` tag... well done!

Comment: i use $_POST['text'];

Comment: /* $text = $_POST['text']; */

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '
<b>hello</b>
this is the first img
<img src="http://localhost/1.png" title="first img" />
other img
<img src="http://localhost/2.png" title="other" />
';

$pattern = '/src=\"(.*?)\"/g';

preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '
<b>hello</b>
this is the first img
<img src="http://localhost/1.png" title="first img" />
other img
<img src="http://localhost/2.png" title="other" />
';

preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+)[\'"].*>/i', $text , $image);
echo $image['src'];
```